# Record incorrect password/key used to attempt to connect to hostapd network

Tags: wireless-networking, hostapd

I've been hosting a `WPA2` network with `hostapd` on my Linux box, and I would like to record the incorrect keys used in failed attempts to connect. If my understanding is correct, the actual password is not transmitted, just the 64-byte PSK, which is all I need. So, how can I configure `hostapd` to log failed attempts to connect along with the keys used in those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Spiff already mentioned neither the password nor the 256-bit pairwise master key PMK (derived from the password and the SSID) are exchanged between station
and access point during the 4-way handshake.

Details on the 4-way handshake can be found e.g. [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17767/four-way-handshake-in-wpa-personal-wpa-psk) or [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/25259/164974).

In the case you are describing (where a wrong password is used), only the first two messages are exchanged:

- In **message 1** the AP sends a nonce (Na) to the station.
- The station uses this nonce (Na) a nonce of his own (Ns), his own MAC address, the MAC addresses of the AP and the PMK to construct a message integrity code (MIC).
- In **message 2** the station then sends his nonce (Ns), and the MIC to the AP.
- The access point now uses his nonce (Na), the nonce of the station (Ns), his own MAC address, the MAC addresses of the station and the PMK to reconstruct the MIC received from the station and to verify with this that the PMK used by the station was correct.
  In the case of a wrong PMK used by the station, the MIC sent by the station in message 2 cannot be verified by the AP. Therefore the AP stops the handshake and does not send message 3 of the handshake.

To the best of my knowledge in userland you don't have access to the content of the EAPOL management frames that are exchanged during the handshake
via an interface exposed by `hostapd`.

Therefore your best option to find out what password was tried, would be to capture the WPA2 handshake (EAPOL frames) with a WiFi card set to monitor mode.
When you have the first two frames of the 4-way handshake in your capture, you have all the information that is needed to in principle recover the password that was used by the station, namely

- Nonce Na
- Nonce Ns
- MAC address of station
- MAC address of AP
- MIC

You can use a tool such as **aircrack-ng** to recover the password via a brute-force or dictionary attack on the captured partial WPA2 handshake.

Answer (score 0):

No, the PSK is not transmitted. It would be a horrible security protocol if it was. Everybody would be spoofing nearby SSIDs just to get clients to reveal their passwords.

There’s no way to do what you’re looking for. If there was, WPA2 would have been replaced long ago.

Comment: Forgetting about PSK's, is there no logging at all when someone tries to connect to a WPA2 network? Or does the AP not even see the traffic unless it's using the right key, or something?

Comment: @Xen2050 hostapd prints a message when someone connects, it just doens't contain the password or key they used.

Comment: @Spiff If the PSK is not transmitted, how does the AP know the client got it right?